# Web API Post method is receiving null vales always

Tags: angularjs, json, asp.net-web-api2

I am developing Wep api2 crud operations with angularjs. Whenever i tried to send data to server it recieves null. I am sending data as below.

```
this.saveUsers = function (users) {
        debugger;
        return $http({
            method: 'post',
            data: users,
            url: "Users",
            contentType: "application/json"
        });
    }
```

This is my Web Api controller POST method.

```
 public IHttpActionResult Post(NCT_UserRegistration users)
        {
        }
```

Here I am recieving always null values. My object is as follows.
$scope.saveUsers = function () {

```
var users = {
        User_EmailId: $scope.User_EmailId,
        User_Password: $scope.User_Password,
        User_Name: $scope.User_Name,
        User_MobileNum: $scope.User_MobileNum,
        User_Status: $scope.User_Status,
        User_Role: $scope.User_Role,
        User_CreatedDate: new Date(),
        User_UpdatedDate: new Date()
    };
This is data for example.
users = Object {User_EmailId: "gff", User_Password: "gfg", User_Name: "fgf", User_MobileNum: "gff", User_Status: "fgfg"…}
```

May i know why I am getting null values always? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried [FromBody] attribute with parameter?

Comment: Thank you.  public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] NCT_UserRegistration users). This is the one right?

Comment: Try making the type of the parameter a string just to see if it gets the data there.

Comment: Not sure about the issue. You can check with stringfy your model in JSON by data: JSON.stringify(users) and pass with having FromBody attrib

Comment: I put string now i am not able to hot to api. I am getting below error angular.js:12185 POST http://localhost:22045/Users 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Comment: Is your NCT_UserRegistration class properties exactly same as properties in your users object.??